# Can I use normal grease for a car on the surface of carbon bike?

Tags: frames, fork, seatpost, headset

Helo Guys,

I want to know your experience about carbon material and grease
Can I use normal grease with carbon ? 
I want to put grease onto fork and stem....

Or WD-40 or silicone penetrant would be ok ?
Thank you....

Can I use this one ?
[image: http://i129.photobucket.com/albums/p231/picture_77/13012012170.jpg]

Comment: I would not advise putting automotive grease anywhere on any bike, especially carbon.

Comment: I've repacked many a hub with automotive wheel bearing grease. For mating carbon surfaces you should use carbon paste, this is a grease with microparticles. It provides a grip between the carbon surfaces. For bearings, grease as normal.

Comment: WD-40 contains solvents that might attack (or at least stain) the resin.

Comment: For any lube you're putting on carbon surfaces I'd check the label to be sure it said "safe for plastics".

Comment: I saw "Safe on Rubber,Metal, Wood & Vinyl", is it ok ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Sheldon Brown](http://sheldonbrown.com/gloss_g.html):

> Grease lubrication is commonly used on all ball bearings. Good mechanics also use grease (or oil) on the threads of most threaded fittings and fasteners, and also inside the steerer (to keep the stem from becoming stuck) and the seat tube (to keep the seatpost from becoming stuck.)
>
> There are a great many different greases on the market with different special features, mainly for automotive applications. For bicycle use, almost any grease is adequate, since the loads and temperatures are generally low.

Seems to me like the answer is *yes*, although to be safe why don't you invest in some [Finish Line Teflon Grease](http://www.finishlineusa.com/products/fortified-grease.htm) - one tube will last you for years. From the Finish Line [website](http://www.finishlineusa.com/frequentquestions/index.htm):

> **Q. Are Finish Line products safe for use on Carbon Fiber Frames and Parts?**
>
> **A. Yes.** All of our products are safe to use on carbon fiber bike parts; our three degreasers, four lubes, our polish, grease, etc are all safe to use on and around carbon fiber bike parts. The exception is our DOT Brake Fluid – you don’t want to get DOT fluid on any painted or finished surface because it’ll attack the paint / finish.

Comment: There is an enormous variation in what is called "grease".  Basic "grease" (of the non-cooking type) is a combination of "soap" (not unlike ordinary hand soap) and an oil.  But modern grease may have many other components and use something other than "soap" for the emulsifier.  Of particular concern with carbon bikes is that something in the grease may attack the resin holding the carbon fibers together.

Comment: @DanielRHicks true enough - the Finish Line stuff is definitely safe though (I'll add it to my answer)

Comment: my grease looks very dark brown and black, and from the ingredients i didn't see anything special

Comment: Can I use WD-40 replacing grease ?

Comment: WD-40 is not a lubricant or grease, it may leave a slippery residue but its definitely not for lubricating.  its a Water Dispersal agent.

Answer (score 0):

Most automotive use grease is too thick for bicycle applications. It will lubricate, but it will add friction to the movement of the bike.

Aside from the "weight" of the grease, you only need to worry about purity.

Phil Wood, of Phil Wood Components, used to say that his most important criteria for his bicycle grease was too make sure it matched the color of his original green sample. If it varied, even a little, he was besieged by inquiries about what he'd changed in his "formula".

Comment: Park Polylube 1000 and White Lightning Crystal Grease are just as thick as automotive wheel bearing grease.

Comment: Go to a motorcycle shop, and ask for wheel bearing lube. Then use it in your bike's hubs. Then try to ride it. It's not the same. Auto/motorcycle grease is designed to be used at high temps. Bike grease doesn't need to be.

Comment: Where did I mention anything about motorcycle grease? I have in fact, repacked more than a few hubs with an automotive wheel bearing grease, a Valvoline Synthetic Blend, specifically. The axle when spun feels no different than had I used bicycle specific grease, and the wheels spin fine with no noticeable resistance.

Comment: “Automotive use grease” is the perfect viscosity for the majority of roller bearing applications that don’t see extremely high rpm’s and aren’t extremely precise, which bicycle bearings are neither, even high end ones. That’s why they call it hub or bearing grease. As it is heated by the friction of movement, it becomes slightly more viscous, but not enough to leak. Most modern bearing greases with any number of synthetic additives also resist water washout. At the speed bearings rotate on a bicycle, the friction coefficient of the grease isn’t going to get in the way.

Answer (score -1):

i would be careful of any type of grease i use on a bike.. Grease attracts the dirt and can lead to further issues on the mechanics of your bike. like stated before - use an oil specially formulated for your bike. and make sure after every cycle to clean your bike down and re-oil.

Comment: Grease is common on bicycles, in headsets, bottom brackets, hubs, seatposts (to prevent them from getting stuck), etc.